# Why is my Ubuntu Core 16 in an endless config loop?

Tags: ubuntu-core

Ubuntu CORE 16 on Orange Pi Zero (armf).

Downloaded and registered.

Found that on fresh image, with no snaps installed, eventually the device drops its IP address and cannot be sshed into.

That might be the pushed updates? The system was warning a reboot was coming through but the device did not appear to come up again after the pushed refresh - except that the serial port persisted with original IP address.

If I hard reboot, the device recovers with a new IP address.

If I sudo reboot before the forced reboot the device reboots and retains the original IP address.   So there is some subtle difference between the user soft reboot happening and the reboot from the refresh.

To top it off, this morning the serial port prompted for the config again.  There was no prompt for ubuntu email address. It prompted for the IP setup.

I answered yes to all questions, and an IP was assigned, the device fell back into the config prompt.  As often as I pushed through the prompts the device would be reassigned and IP and then fall back into the config prompt.

I have tried this on two OPiZ boards to confirm that the board was not flaky.

Ubuntu CORE 16 (armf) for Orange Pi Zero is not release ready.

Good luck sorting that but why would it be released in that condition?

Comment: Huh, I've never seen that before. Would you mind please creating a post over in the snapcraft forum? https://forum.snapcraft.io/c/device

Comment: So, this is uninteresting to the ubuntu-core community?  You are speaking on behalf of Ubuntu right?

Comment: Not at all, I'm merely suggesting that this sounds like a problem that needs troubleshooting, not a question that needs answering (i.e. this is not the best platform for triaging issues).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the Ubuntu update mechanism and delays on the internet.  There is what I call the doldrums which is southern hemisphere is blocked out of access to northern hemisphere servers when northern hemisphere is awake and users are throttling servers.

Whenever I try connecting to ubuntu core device at night time southern hemisphere I will often get a snap does not exist message or connection timeout with some message about missing headers.  This is just round trip problem over the internet over distances and server loading.

This morning (saturday morning southern hemisphere and northern hemisphere asleep) I reburnt the Ubuntu CORE 16 Orange Pi onto SD, loaded it, started device, let device go through it's obligatory first update and it came back up! That is it did not lock into config loop after update came through.

This indicates that the update, also prone to having to travel across planet, is sensitive to timeouts and frags the device that is updating.

Therefore, snap technology, binding to commercial entity in northern hemisphere appears unfriendly to southern hemisphere.

The only solution, since you cannot avoid the updates, is to set the updates to quiet time in northern hemisphere.